# How to match multiple lines words using regex expression

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

As title describled,I want to match multiple lines words with regex expression begin with "No" and end with "e".Here is the sample below:

Special Instructions
No
t fo
r c
us
tom
er 
sig
na
tur
e
Table Of Contents
Customer Details 1
Site Details 2
Tom Tom Sales B.V. German Branch 2
Dynamic Bandwidth 6
Billing Details 7

What I really want is like this:

Special Instructions

Table Of Contents
Customer Details 1
Site Details 2
Tom Tom Sales B.V. German Branch 2
Dynamic Bandwidth 6
Billing Details 7

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern with multiline **and** singleline options:

```
@"^No\r?\n.*?^e\r?\n"
```

example:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^No\r?\n.*?^e\r?\n",
      RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.Singleline);
string result = rgx.Replace(yourstr, "");
```

pattern description:

```
^        # anchor for the start of the line (because the multiline option is 
         # used, otherwise ^ is an anchor for the start of the string)
No
\r?\n    # an optional carriage return and a line feed
.*?      # all characters zero or more times (the dot can match newlines since 
         # the singleline option is used, the dot can't match newlines with the 
         # default behavior)
^        # anchor for the start of the line
e        #
\r?\n    # if you want to preserve the last CRLF you could replace this with $
         # ($ is an anchor for the end of the line in multiline mode, in default
         # mode, $ means "end of the string")
```

Comment: Thanks,It's helpful.Maybe I should study regex expression first!

Comment: @Michael: I added a description of the pattern.